# Kohana 3 – any easier than Kohana 2?

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-2

All the way while I have been trying to migrate from Kohana 2 to Kohana 3.2 in a new project, I was wondering **how is it better**?

- There is an [evidence](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/3534/kohana-3-performance/p1) that databases work slower in Kohana 3
- Captcha module was left out of the framework (so that one need's to search in [forum](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/9426/solved-ko-3-2-kohana-captcha-module-issues/p1) to solve the problem by hacking the old module)
- There's a mess in Kohana 3.x documentation (you meet things documented only for Kohana 3.0 or 3.1, though there can be big changes in versions)
- Finally, my application does not produce ANY output on certain types of mistakes, what I never met with Kohana 2. — Can't figure why. (*Resolved:* new host doesn't display errors.)

Obviously, I feel sorry the developers left the good old Kohana 2.x branch, because all I need is an easy and stable solution for quite simple applications.

The question is, what are the advantages of Kohana 3.x that make it worth its disadvantages compared to Kohana 2.x? (I mean the kind of advantages, that make the programmer's life easier and save time.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- HMVC out of the box
- Light core (a lot of optional classes where moved into separated modules)
- New routing system!! Its so cool, and Im really hate 2.3.x routes
- Userguide module. Write your docs with automatically generated API
- Config writers (v3.2+)
- Improved error handling (especially in 3.3)
- `Minion` module (v3.3) - CLI tasks with Kohana features!

Comment: I must admit, that Kohana 3 is still a great framework. Some things are improved and one just needs to get used to its little drawbacks.

Comment: Because its not far from stable release ;)